# Node.js error : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to NodeJs and I'm dealing with an issue while running my application.I'm trying to make a page for an image contest and I want to show on the homepage the newest comments,attaching to them the image where the comments were posted. The error that I get looks like this: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, making refference to my code `at model.<anonymous> (\rootproject\models\comment.js:15:16)`.

The entire error code looks like this:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at model.Document.set (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:526:
34)
    at model.set [as image] (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:19
01:25)
    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\models\comment.js:15:16)
    at VirtualType.applySetters (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\virtualtyp
e.js:94:25)
    at model.Document.set (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:694:
12)
    at model.set [as image] (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:19
01:25)
    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\models\comment.js:15:16)
    at VirtualType.applySetters (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\virtualtyp
e.js:94:25)
    at model.Document.set (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:694:
12)
    at model.set [as image] (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:19
01:25)
    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\models\comment.js:15:16)
    at VirtualType.applySetters (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\virtualtyp
e.js:94:25)
    at model.Document.set (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:694:
12)
    at model.set [as image] (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:19
01:25)
    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\models\comment.js:15:16)
    at VirtualType.applySetters (C:\Users\Rares\Desktop\rootproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\virtualtyp
e.js:94:25)
```

Here is my code for comment.js file:

```
var models = require('../models'),
async = require('async');

module.exports = {
newest: function(callback) {
    models.Comment.find({}, {}, {
            limit: 5,
            sort: {
                'timestamp': -1
            }
        },
        function(err, comments) {
            var attachImage = function(comment, next) {
                models.Image.findOne({
                        _id: comment.image_id
                    },
                    function(err, image) {
                        if (err) throw err;

                        comment.image = image;
                        next(err);
                    });
            };

            async.each(comments, attachImage,
                function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    callback(err, comments);
                });
        });

}
};
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you doing in `async.each`?

Comment: I'm using `async.each` to loop through every item in the `comments` collection and send each item as a parameter to the callback function `attachImage`.The third parameter is supposed to be the callback function that is executed once the entire series is finished with the collection.

Comment: Looks like your `Comment` schema has [a virtual setter](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) that's calling itself (perhaps indirectly through another schema?).

Comment: My comment model looks like this : 

`var CommentSchema = new Schema({

    image_id : { type : ObjectId },

    email: { type : String },

    name: { type : String },

    gravatar: { type : String },

    comment: { type : String },

    timestamp: { type : Date, 'default': Date.now }

});


CommentSchema.virtual('image').set(function(image){

    this.image = image;

}).get(function(){

    return this._image;

});`